# How to use regex with kwic to get all matches?

Tags: r, regex, quanteda

I can't seem to get the desired output using quanteda's `qwic`. Here's what I've tried:

```
library(quanteda)
library(tidyverse)
```

Given this text

```
text <- "This is a phone number: 222-222-2222. Here's another phone number...(111)111 1111. This -- 333-3333 -- aint a complete phone number."
```

Here's a regex that matches for most US phone numbers along with any characters each side of the number

```
regex.phone1 <- "\\D\\(?\\d{3}\\)?[.\\s-]?\\s*\\d{3}[.\\s-]?\\s*[.\\s-]*\\d{4}\\D"
```

It matches the first number here, which means the regex is working as expected.

```
regmatches(text,regexpr(regex.phone1,text))

" 222-222-2222."
```

But kwic doesn't match anything.
This:

```
 kwic(
  x = text,
  pattern = regex.phone1,
  window = 5,
  valuetype = "regex",
  case_insensitive = TRUE
) %>%
  as_tibble
```

returns:

```
A tibble: 0 x 7
… with 7 variables: docname <chr>, from <int>, to <int>, pre <chr>, keyword <chr>,
  post <chr>, pattern <fct>
```

My desire is to have it match all phone numbers, which in this case is:

"222-222-2222."

".(111)111 1111."

(and put those in the normal form of the kwic output that displays pre, post, and more).

Comment: Not sure how `kwic` works but you can use the pattern in `str_extract_all` to extract all the words that satisfy the pattern. `stringr::str_extract_all(text, regex.phone1)[[1]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to match the phone numbers by making `phrases` from regular expressions.

```r
library(quanteda)
library(tidyverse)

text <- "This is a number: 541 145-8884 also 222-222-2222 Here's (444)111-1111. No. 555 666 7774"

kwic(
  x = text,
  phrase(c("^[\\d]{10}$","^[\\d]{3} [\\d]{3}-[\\d]{4}$","^[\\d]{3}-[\\d]{3}-[\\d]{4}$","^[\\d]{3} [\\d]{3} [\\d]{4}$","^[(] [\\d]{3} [)] [\\d]{3}-[\\d]{4}$")),
  window = 3,
  valuetype = "regex",
  separator = " ",
  case_insensitive = FALSE
) %>%
  
print(as_tibble)

# Output:                                                                                                 
#   [text1, 6:7]                a number: |   541 145-8884   | also 222-222-2222 Here's
#   [text1, 9:9]        541 145-8884 also |   222-222-2222   | Here's( 444             
# [text1, 11:14] also 222-222-2222 Here's | ( 444 ) 111-1111 | . No.                   
# [text1, 18:20]                    . No. |   555 666 7774   |
```

Comment: Also, my original regex matched a number that was preceded by a non-lettter, but your's doesn't. It should match for this `# preceded by a character -111-111-1111. and followed by a non-# too`

Comment: Also, it should match with this: `1112223333` (but maybe that wasn't in my original spec!)

Comment: I've edited the answer, it'll now match `1112223333`. In your first comment I didn't understand which type of numbers you want to match, can you give me some examples?